# Как вывести список диалогов VK

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Нужно вывести список диалогов Вконтакте с названием и картинкой (отображение похоже на список друзей в мобильном клиенте), остальное неважно.

Использую com.vk:androidsdk.
Использую метод `messages.getDialogs` из VkApi. Возвращает JSON с массивом из 20 элементов с данными. Для каждого элемента из массива выдергиваю имя/название и картинку отдельным методом (`messages.getChat/users.get/groups.getById` в зависимости от типа диалога). После 6 элементов получаю ошибку:

> VKError (API errorVKError (code: 6; ; Too many requests per second)).

Моя проблема аналогична: http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=60&topic=6744.
Другой вариант, который рассматривает автор:

> Есть другой вариант, запрос сделать сразу на всех пользователей, указать в параметре ID-шники через запятую

Он не подходит, т.к. у нас могут быть диалоги не только с пользователями, но и с сообществами, а так же чаты. Получается нужно разбивать элементы на 3 массива: чаты (метод `messages.getChat`), пользователи (метод `users.get`) и сообщества (метод `groups.getById`).

При вышеописанном решении получается 4 запроса (вместе с `messages.getDialogs`). Если они выполнятся за 1 секунду, то получим ту же ошибку.

Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Проблема при вызове за одну секунду - используйте `execute`, а так - на получение списка диалогов есть ограничение (200 за раз), так что нужно делать несколько запросов в любом случае (если диалогов больше 200)

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/execute - ваше всё

Comment: @PeterSamokhin спасибо, я думал может есть и другие способы. Насчет нескольких запросов messages.getDialogs понятно, но сможет ли пользователь прокрутить 200 диалогов в адаптере менее, чем за 1 секунду?