# C# VK API получить имя пользователя в списке диалогов

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, uwp

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. В VK API метод messages.getDialogs возвращает только id пользователя\чата\группы. Чтобы вывести нормальный список диалогов с именами, названиями групп, нужно сделать 2 - 3 запроса: получить список диалогов => по id получить список пользователей => если это не пользователь, а группа (id начинается с -), то опять сделать запрос и получить имя группы => и если это еще не группа, а к примеру, письмо, отправленное на почту, то id будет -2000000000 id...

Аналогичный вопрос есть вот здесь => [Как вывести список диалогов VK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725952/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2-vk)

Однако, метод execute - не совсем уместный вариант, т.к. я пишу мобильное приложение. Подскажите более адекватный способ получения вменяемого списка диалогов и оптимизацией запросов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом:

1. Сделал запрос к вк методом messages.getDialogs
2. Разобрал `response`
3. Разделил id пользователей и id сообществ, поместив их в разные переменные через запятую.
4. Сделал множественный запрос `execute`, с предварительной проверкой на пустоту переменной groupIds.
5. Разобрал `response` из метода `execute` и поместил его в новый JSON массив, затем сделал результат возвращаемым.

Обращался за помощью по другому вопросу сюда и пример моего кода находится  [вот здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770087/c-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%83-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)