# C# отсортировать список по индексу другого списка

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется `List<string>` с получаемыми данными из VK. В нем хранятся Id пользователей.

Эти данные перебираются и делается множественный запрос (`execute`) на получение имени пользователей и групп.
В `response` хранится json из двух массивов: первый - результат запроса `users.get`, второй - результат запроса `groups.getById`. Эти данные записываются в другой JSON, в котором после этого должны возвращаться функцией и использоваться в другом участке кода.

Проблема: при записи элементов в JArray, они сортируются не в порядке диалогов, а сперва значения запроса `users.get`, а затем `groups.getById`, тем самым индексы (и расположение) элементов JArray расположены в таком порядке: 
`0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
9`

Где, "9" - это данные группы. Группы в список добавляются в самый конец, и все значения в списке "смещаются". Как можно поместить 9 на свое место?

**UPDATE:**
Предварительно, все идентификаторы во время разбора response метода messages.getDialogs помещаются в переменные groupIds и userIds соответственно.
             А так же абсолютно все идентификаторы (и групп, и пользователей) помещаются в List idList; (В этом участке кода этого не показано.)
Привожу пример кода:

```
             //Подготовка множественного запроса к VK API.
         //userids - string - с id пользователей через запятую. Записываются при разборе response messages.getDialogs. 
        string method = "API.users.get({\"user_ids\":\"" + userIds + "\", \"fields\":\"photo_50\"})";

         //groupIds - string - с id групп через запятую. Записываются так же при разборе response messages.getDialogs.
         //Если строка не пустая, то к множественному запросу присоеденить запрос по получению данных группы
        if (groupIds.Length > 0)
            method += ", API.groups.getById({\"group_ids\":\"" + groupIds + "\"})";

        // Множественный запрос (execute)
        var request = JObject.Parse(await BatchRequest(method));
        string uid = "";
        string name = "";
        string avatar = "";

        // JArray, в который помещаю id, name, avatar пользователей и групп вместе.
        JArray preparedJson = new JArray();

        foreach (var data in request["response"])
        {
            if (data is JArray)
            {
                foreach (var arr in data)
                {
                    if (arr["uid"] == null && arr["gid"] != null)
                    {
                        uid = arr["gid"].ToString();
                        name = arr["name"].ToString();
                        avatar = arr["photo"].ToString();
                    } else
                    {
                        uid = arr["uid"].ToString();
                        name = arr["first_name"].ToString() + " " + arr["last_name"].ToString();
                        avatar = arr["photo_50"].ToString();
                    }

                    user.uid = uid;
                    user.name = name;
                    user.avatar = avatar;

                    // Собственно, само помещение объекта User (с полями uid,name,avatar) в JArray.
                    preparedJson.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
                }
            }
        }


        // Перебор Json так, как это перебиралось бы в другом методе, вызывающий этот
        foreach (var data in preparedJson)
        {
            var json = JObject.Parse(data.ToString());
            // Собственно, выведет список из значений json, записанных ранее. В порядке, в котором описаны в вопросе
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);

            // Выводит индексы всех идентификаторов. Вывод получается смешанным - сперва идут пользователи, и в самом конце группа. Вывод указан в вопросе.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(idList.IndexOf(json["uid"].ToString()));
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
Привожу значения списков:
idList:

```
        26094570
        32375480
        46086417
        2505581
        24862495
        6123568
        701580
        25081541
        16111376
        30242512
        31238032
        5927769
        -15736980
        27044567
        42927784
        1028357
        15203959
        3042183
        29652691
        27378364
```

Это идентификаторы пользователей в списке диалогов. По сути это и есть список диалогов, только с ID пользователей и групп (без их сообщений и т.д.).

А это значения из JArray preparedJson:

```
        { "uid":"26094570","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"32375480","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"46086417","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"2505581","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"24862495","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"6123568","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"701580","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"25081541","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"16111376","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"30242512","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"31238032","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"5927769","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"27044567","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"42927784","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"1028357","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"15203959","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"3042183","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"29652691","name":"username","avatar":""}
        { "uid":"27378364","name":"username","avatar":"avatar"}
        { "uid":"-15736980","name":"groupname","avatar":"avatar"}
```

Обратите внимание на порядок идентификаторов. В моих диалогах id группы идет после id `5927769`, а здесь в самом конце списка. Весь мой вопрос состоит в том, КАК последний id списка (группу) переместить на свое место, после id `5927769`?

Comment: А можно пример данных и кода? А то не очень понятно, что происходит.

Comment: @VladD добавил пример кода

Comment: Поместите пожалуйста в вопрос сам JSON ответ, который вы разбираете.

Comment: Метод [Array.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) имеет множество перегрузок. Как я понял, вам нужна `Sort(Array, Array)`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не сработало :(

Comment: @СергейИгнахин поместил еще данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так. Во-первых, положил бы данные в словарь: вместо `JArray preparedJson = new JArray();` написал бы `var usersById = new Dictionary<string, User>();`, а вместо

```
user.uid = uid;
user.name = name;
user.avatar = avatar;

// Собственно, само помещение объекта User (с полями uid,name,avatar) в JArray.
preparedJson.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
```

соответственно

```
var user = new User() { uid = uid, name = name, avatar = avatar };
usersById[uid] = user;
```

А после окончания цикла собрал бы данные:

```
JArray preparedJson = new JArray();
foreach (var id in idList)
    preparedJson.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(usersById[id]));
```

Ну или с проверкой:

```
foreach (var id in idList)
    if (usersById.TryGetValue(id, out var user))
        preparedJson.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
```

---

Ещё один вариант с LINQ. После цикла `foreach (var data in request["response"]) { ... }` добавьте:

```
preparedJson = new JArray(
    from id in ids join user in preparedJson on id equals user["uid"] select user);
```

(надеюсь, что порядок в `join`'е определён однозначно). Это и есть та самая сортировка по элементу в другом массиве.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил проверку на существование ключа в словаре, а то может и упасть)

Comment: @СергейИгнахин: Угу, наверное так лучше. Но это уже шлифовка.

Comment: Офигеть, работает! Неделю потратил на раздумия, решил сюда обратиться. Спасибо!!

Comment: @VladD, можете объяснить, пожалуйста, как работает строка
usersById[uid] = user? Я в C# новичок, и думал, что добавлять в dictionary можно с помощью Add();

Comment: @4L3X: В словарь можно добавлять и через Add, и через индексатор. В индексаторе, если помните, есть отдельно геттер и сеттер, вот в сеттере оно и добавляется.

Comment: @4L3X: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 2):

Фильтрацию можно выполнить следующим образом пройтись по всем значениям пользователей и найти и добавить все совпадения в новую коллекцию. Также работать с JArray неудобно потому я выполнил десериализацию в модель.
Пример:

```
class Program
{

    public class RequestModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<RequestRow> Data { get; set; }

    }

    public class RequestRow
    {
        [JsonProperty("uid")]
        public string Uid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("avatar")]
        public string Avatar { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Десериализуем данные для удобства работы
        var request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestModel>(GetJsonString());

        //Получаем список пользователей
        var userIds = GetUsersIds();

        //Создаем коллекцию в которую добавим только те элементы и в таком порядке как указанно в списке
        var newList = new List<RequestRow>();

        //Непосредственная фильтрация
        foreach (var userId in userIds)
        {
            var row = request.Data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Uid == userId);
            if (row != null)
            {
                newList.Add(row);
            }
        }

        //Ну и выведем для наглядности
        foreach (var requestRow in newList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(requestRow.Uid);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение списка ID
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> GetUsersIds()
    {
        return new List<string>()
            {
                "26094570",
                "32375480",
                "46086417",
                "2505581",
                "24862495",
                "6123568",
                "701580",
                "25081541",
                "16111376",
                "30242512",
                "31238032",
                "5927769",
                "-15736980",
                "27044567",
                "42927784",
                "1028357",
                "15203959",
                "3042183",
                "29652691",
                "27378364"
            };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Получение исходной строки JSON
    /// </summary>
    public static string GetJsonString()
    {
        var result =
            @"
                {
                  ""data"": [
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""26094570"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""32375480"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""46086417"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""2505581"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""24862495"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""6123568"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""701580"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""25081541"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""16111376"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""30242512"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""31238032"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""5927769"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""27044567"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""42927784"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""1028357"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""15203959"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""3042183"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""29652691"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": """"
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""27378364"",
                      ""name"": ""username"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    },
                    {
                      ""uid"": ""-15736980"",
                      ""name"": ""groupname"",
                      ""avatar"": ""avatar""
                    }
                  ]
                }";
        return result;
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения:

```
26094570
32375480
46086417
2505581
24862495
6123568
701580
25081541
16111376
30242512
31238032
5927769
-15736980
27044567
42927784
1028357
15203959
3042183
29652691
27378364
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Оба ответа очень ценны и рабочие! :))

Comment: @4L3X, пожалуйста. Обращайтесь)